# In HTML5, please explain the meaning of '?' in the statement

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

In HTML5, what is the meaning of '?' in this statement? What's the meaning of content after the '?'?

```
<script type='text/javascript'
        src='http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.js?ver=3.1-20121105'>
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

In HTML 5, nothing. It is just part of a URL.

In this case, it indicates the start of the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), which a process on the server may give special attention to.

It might also give no special meaning to it whatsoever, but be there just so the URL is *different* to avoid older, cached versions of the same file being reused after changes were made to it.

Answer (score 0):

In url After `?` indicates that after this all are parameters (key value pair). Here `ver` is a key and `3.1-20121105` is value

Answer (score 0):

This is a part of URL after `?` called as query string. If you need some params to pass to another page through URL then you can use query string. So in the url `http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.js?ver=3.1-20121105` `ver` is the key and `3.1-20121105` is the value. It seems like you the url will loads `3.1-20121105` version of thickbox.js.

Answer (score 0):

According to the URI RFC, the ? is a start of the query list.

For more information on different parts of URIs, see [this document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3).